# divs slider with custom pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

i need to develop a slider / carousel like this exactly you can see the [example](http://www.alfaromeo.co.uk/models/giulietta#dynamism) in the site

i pasted the code and tried to study it but i got lost with scripts and the divs background not loaded!

simply i need to sliding three or more divs with custom pagination float on and every div is stretched to the browser page with background image cover like the example i mentioned before. Thank you

```css
@media screen and (min-width:769px){.slider-menu{width:100%;font-size:0;position:absolute;right:0;bottom:42px;left:0;text-align:center;z-index:4}
.slider-menu>ul,.slider-menu>ul>li{display:inline-block}
.slider-menu>ul{padding:0;font-size:0;width:100%}
.slider-menu>ul>li{font:14px/14px "ApexNew-Medium",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#000;background-color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;border-right:1px solid #000;cursor:pointer;max-width:180px;width:100%;text-align:center}
.slider-menu>ul>li:first-child{position:relative}
.slider-menu>ul>li:first-child:before{content:"";width:90%;height:1px;position:absolute;bottom:5px;left:5%;background:#8f0c25}
.slider-menu>ul>li:last-child{border-right:0}
.slider-menu>ul>li.active{background-color:#8f0c25;color:#fff}
}
@media screen and (min-width:1366px){.slider-menu>ul>li{max-width:220px}
}
```

```html
<div class="section row-slide"><div class="item--mobile wrap-item isActive inView" data-fx="slide" data-ancor-target="dynamism" >
 <div class="slider-item__wrap" data-item-count="" >
  
   <div class="slide current" >
    <article class="model-item">
     <div class="model-item__col pos-bottom-left js-responsive-image" data-src-medium="/content/dam/alfaromeo/global/model/giulietta/tablet/dynamism_modelapge-newgiulietta_medium.jpg" data-src-small="/content/dam/alfaromeo/global/model/giulietta/mobile/dynamism_modelpage-newgiulietta_small.jpg" data-src="/content/dam/alfaromeo/global/model/giulietta/desktop/dynamism_modelapge-newgiulietta.jpg" style=" background-image: url(&quot;/content/dam/alfaromeo/global/model/giulietta/desktop/dynamism_modelapge-newgiulietta.jpg&quot;);">
      
      <div class="model-item__row">
       <div class="color--light model__content left">
        <h2 class="content__title">
         DYNAMISM
        </h2>
        <div class="content__text">
         <span class="animated-line"></span>
         <p>CREATED TO MASTER THE ROAD</p>



        </div>
        <div class="content__descr">
         <p>Each element of the New Alfa Giulietta has been designed to perfectly balance power and agility for every road condition, achieving extraordinary driving pleasure.&nbsp;</p>

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </article>
   </div>
  
   <div class="slide" >
    <article class="model-item">
     <div class="model-item__col pos-bottom-left js-responsive-image" data-src-medium="/content/dam/alfaromeo/global/model/giulietta/tablet/dna_modelpage-newgiulietta_medium.jpg" data-src-small="/content/dam/alfaromeo/global/model/giulietta/mobile/dna_modelpage-newgiulietta_small.jpg" data-src="/content/dam/alfaromeo/global/model/giulietta/desktop/dna_modelpage-newgiulietta.jpg" style="height: 544px; background-image: url(&quot;/content/dam/alfaromeo/global/model/giulietta/desktop/dna_modelpage-newgiulietta.jpg&quot;);">
      
      <div class="model-item__row">
       <div class="color--light model__content left">
        <h2 class="content__title">
         Alfa D.N.A.
        </h2>
        <div class="content__text">
         <span class="animated-line"></span>
         <p>DYNAMIC CONTROL</p>

        </div>
        <div class="content__descr">
         <p>The Alfa D.N.A. system is the exclusive Alfa Romeo driving mode selector which adapts the vehicle’s performance to suit the driver’s style and road conditions. There are three modes: Dynamic,&nbsp;for performance,&nbsp;Natural&nbsp;for optimum fuel economy and&nbsp;All-Weather for tackling bad weather and low grip conditions.</p>  
         
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </article>
   </div>
  
   <div class="slide">
    <article class="model-item">
     <div class="model-item__col pos-bottom-left js-responsive-image" style="background-image:url(images/models/giulietta/dynamism_modelapge-newgiulietta.jpg);">
      
      <div class="model-item__row">
       <div class=" model__content pos--right">
        <h2 class="content__title">
         SUSPENSION
        </h2>
        <div class="content__text">
         <span class="animated-line"></span>
         <p>FEEL THE ROAD</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content__descr">
         <p>Sporty, fun, yet comfortable: the New Alfa Giulietta is equipped to deliver the authentic Alfa Romeo driving experience. The Macpherson front suspension and Multilink rear suspension have been designed to offer great road holding and a superior level of comfort. This combination offers a truly involving drive with no loss in refinement.</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </article>
   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- END contenitore elemento con scroll orizzontale -->
 <!-- START Menu per scroll orrizzontale -->
 <div class="slider-menu">
  <ul class="slider-menu__items">
   <li class="active" data-adobe="content::dynamism">
    DYNAMISM
   </li>
   <li data-adobe="content::alfadna">
    Alfa D.N.A.
   </li>
   <li data-adobe="content::suspension">
    SUSPENSION
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <!-- END Menu per scroll orrizzontale -->
 <!-- START pulsanti di avanzamento alla slide successiva nel data target deve esser contenuto il data-ancor-target della slide successiva -->
 <div class="mobile-next-navigation" data-target="efficiency">EFFICIENCY</div>
 <!-- END pulsanti di avanzamento alla slide successiva -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included necessary plugin for the slider?

Comment: You can create a slider JQUERY/CSS using cssslider http://cssslider.com/

Comment: I made a fiddle of their code: the background doesn't load but I put  the full path in so maybe have another go at tweaking the css yourself. A starting point! https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jazLgwzy/

Comment: unfortunately not working!

Answer (score 0):

please check this link : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/osdLso66/

HTML :

```
<div id="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

          <div class="item" style='background-image:url("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg")'></div>
          <div class="item" style='background-image:url("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg")'></div>
          <div class="item" style='background-image:url("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/14/01/41/image-view-1139204_960_720.jpg")'></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The style of each item in the slider which you can change its height :

```
.item{
  height:350px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This is the necessary plugins for the slider :

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css
```

and finally the slider script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

    navigation : true,
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem : true
  });
});
```

Comment: This is simple enough but i need to customize the navigation not generated bullets. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: You can customize the navigation using css, I edit its style here check this : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/osdLso66/2/

Comment: thank you so much but i need to develop a custom navigation with different link not just generated bullets.. scroll down please then you will see for example the Technology section and thats what i need to do